# react: использование setState в конструкторе компонента при асинхронных операциях

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, конструктор, setstate

в компоненте в конструкторе делаю запрос на сервер для получения необходимых данных и асинхронно вношу их в состояния:

```
class MyComponent extends Component<any, any> {

    // конструктор
    constructor(
        props: any
    ) {
        super(props);

        // задать состояние компонента
        this.state = {
            data: [1, 2, 3]
        };

        // отправить запрос на сервер
        to_server().then((output: any) => {
            // установить состояния
            this.setState({
                data: output.data,
            });
        });    
    }

    // отрисовать компонент
    render() {
        return <>{this.state.data.length}</>;
    }
}
```

и получаю предупреждение о том, что в конструкторе надо использовать прямую установка состояний:

> Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted.
> This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.
> Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};`
> class property with the desired state in the MyComponent component.

Подскажите как покорректнее решить данную проблему и избавиться от предупреждения.

Comment: Не может быть в приведённом коде такого сообщения если `to_server()` возвращает промис.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В React внутри constructor должны задаваться значения "по умолчанию" для компонента и желательно их планировать так, как будто новых данных больше не будет.

> Метод React **componentDidMount()** лучшее место для установки таймеров, слушателей(listner), выполнения сетевых запросов. 
> Аналог метода **componentDidMount()** в функциональных компонентах React `useEffect()` -> Вызов useEffect с зависимостью []

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(`Я установился в DOM`)
}, []);
```

Если ваше приложение предполагает удаление компонента из DOM, то не забывайте удалять таймеры и слушатели в методе componentWillUnmount()

> Метод React **componentWillUnmount()** вызывается перед удалением компонента из DOM. 
> Аналог в функциональных компонентах, это в `useEffect()` реализовать метод `return`, который должен возвращать функцию, в которой указаны обработчики действий по очистке данных.
>
> ```js
> useEffect(() => {
>   const timer = setInterval(() => {
>     console.log(`Я установился в DOM`)
>   }, 1000);
>   
>   return () => {
>     clearTimer(timer);
>   }
> }, []);
> ```

Относительно вашего примера, для того, что бы устранить ошибку, достаточно вызов функции перенести в метод **componentDidMount()**. 
Так же добавим проверку, что если данных нет, то рендерить сообщение, что приложение ожидает данные от сервера.

```
class MyComponent extends Component<any, any> {

    // конструктор
    constructor(
        props: any
    ) {
        super(props);

        // задать состояние компонента
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };   
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        // отправить запрос на сервер
        to_server().then((output: any) => {
            // установить состояния
            this.setState({
                data: output.data,
            });
        }); 
    }

    // отрисовать компонент
    render() {
        if (this.state.data.length) {
            return <>{this.state.data.length}</>;
        } else {
            return <>Waiting data...</>; // или возвращать null
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: смущает, что `componentDidMount` вызывается после первой отрисовки, а хотелось бы, чтоб и первая отрисовка шла уже с актуальными данными или это не критично?

Comment: В целом не критично. Но реакт всегда сначала ставит компонент, потом берет пропсы(если есть) и заново ставит компонент. Можно в рендер добавить проверку и не рисовать до тех пор, пока данных нет

Comment: Я подправил ответ и добавил в него, как можно не рисовать компонент, когда данных нет. Но избежать рендера компонента не возможно.

Comment: @Zhihar, и каким же образом она будет с актуальными данными, если запрос асинхронный?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, действительно, так что все ок тогда, смело можно вынимать из конструктора данный функционал

Comment: @Zhihar вы учитывайте что реакт может создать компонент и выкинуть его не отрисовывая. Вам точно надо совершать при этом запрос?

Comment: А в какой ситуации это может произойти? Вроде как у меня всегда нужен запрос